# Sweetalert pop-up message with JavaScript when user hits Submit button

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I need a success message to pop-up when a user hits the `Submit` button. I tried to make a javascript file to solve the task, but something should be wrong because it does nothing.

The Button(HTML):

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="sendMessageButton" action="form.js">Küldés</button>
```

Javascript file:

```
$("#sendMessageButton").click(function(){
Swal.fire(
    'Good job!',
    'You clicked the button!',
    'success'
    );
});
```

Console Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (form.js:2) at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2) at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser js console ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (form.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: "Küldés" - magyarok mindenhol 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on top of your HTML you need to add a reference to sweetAlert:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

then everything should work.

https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download

Answer (score 0):

have you loaded sweetalert cdn?
if yes then go for this..

```
$("#sendMessageButton").click(function(){
swal({
    title: "Good Job",
    text: "You clicked the button!.",
    type: "success"
},
function () {
    //thing which you want to do on click the button of alert
    //location.reload();
});
});
```

Comment: No I haven't, this was the problem. Thank you :)